# Почему память в одном и том же коде течёт в тестах, но не течет без них? (Nodejs, Jest)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jest

При запуске следующего кода напрямую и через jest я получаю совершенно разные результаты. Почему так происходит и как эту проблему можно решить?

```js
function checkMemory(string) {
    global?.gc();
    var used = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
    console.log(string + ' ' + Math.round(used * 100) / 100 + " MB");
}

function memoryLeak(cb) {
    checkMemory('Начальное измерение');

    (() => {
        let string = 'wefwef';

        for (let i = 0; i < 3000000; i++) {
            string += 'wefwef';
        }

        checkMemory('Промежуточное измерение');

        setTimeout(() => {
            string += 'Утечка памяти';
        }, 1000)
    })();

    setTimeout(() => {
        checkMemory('Финальное измерение');
        cb();
    }, 3000);
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    it('Проверяем код на предмет утечки памяти', function (cb) {
        memoryLeak(cb);
    });
} else {
    memoryLeak(() => {
        process.exit();
    });
}
```

Версии jest и node js:
jest == 25.5.4
node == 14.17.3

Comment: Хочу уточнить, что запускаю скрипт я всегда с использованием --expose-gc флага

Comment: А почему вы считаете что память течёт и в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Разве я не вполне понятно описал проблему? Даже прочитав ваш вопрос мне нечего добавить к своему изначальному описанию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, это проблема `jest` версии `25.5.4`. В последней версии такой проблемы уже нет.